# AMD Ryzen 3200G (Picasso) APU Drivers

Tags: drivers, kde, amd-ryzen

I am planning on switch my main OS back from Windows 10, Completely fed up with sfc/scans and repeatedly having BSOD issues.  Never a hardware failure, constantly corrupt windows files.

Since I am using the Ryzen 3 -3200g (Vega 8), I am questioning installing a distro, since I haven't came across the best support for this new APU, or a great repo for it at least.  I ran Manjoro KDE Plasma 18.1.0, from a bootable USB, and was unable to load a good driver successfully.

ANY and all help appreciated!!!

Comment: Even I am struggling with the same issue. The official webpage for AMD Ryzen 3 3200G processor only lists Windows 10 drivers. I thought AMD drivers were supported out-of-the-box on Linux. I chose this processor because it comes with Radeon Vega 8 graphics integrated. Sadly this doesn't seem to be the case with this processor. I tried installing the open source amd-gpu drivers. But I have found that installing those renders my Ubuntu installation unusable (screen goes blank, only VGA output works).