# Ubuntu isn't using AMD or Nvidia drivers properly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, amd-ryzen

I recently purchased an Asus Zenbook 14 Q407IQ. It uses a Ryzen 5 4500U processor with Vega 6 graphics and an Nvidia MX350 dedicated gpu. I've tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 on the laptop and it initially seems to work alright, but it runs very hot and it is very laggy when trying to display animations and the fans are always very loud.

I ended up figuring out that it doesn't seem to be properly configured to use either GPU. It preinstalled with the proprietary Nvidia 440 drivers so I tried updating it to the latest 450 driver but it didn't do anything. I also tried accessing the Nvidia X server settings but it just shows up blank with a quit button. I then tried using `xrandr --listproviders` to see attached graphics drivers but it just says providers number: 0. There also don't seem to be too many instances of this happening for others, but it might just be because Zen 2 APU's are new and don't seem to be paired often with Nvidia GPU's. The only similar instance I found was from [this article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/04/linux-on-laptops-asus-zephyrus-g14-with-ryzen-9-4900hs/) from ArsTechnica that also uses an AMD apu and Nvidia setup and under GPU testing they have a very similar issue to what I'm having and tried some different solutions, but eventually gives up trying to make it work. I've also seen a couple people mentioning disabling one of the GPU's should work, but my Asus laptop does not give me that option. Is it just impossible to use Ubuntu with my current setup for the time being until there is better support for switchable Nvidia/AMD apu graphics? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which NVIDIA driver is your system using? According to [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/184163/en-us), it should be version 470.94. You can check it from this Nvidia [website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). On your system, open `Software & Update`  app then got to `Additional Drivers` to check your driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just impossible to use Ubuntu with my current setup for the time being until there is better support for switchable Nvidia/AMD apu graphics?

I would assume you can use this system with 1 GPU disabled.
But for dual support you will probably need kernel support or a new version of bumblebee.
Or if you have a lot of time on your hands create a manual configuration for both and then merge those like we used to do when we needed 3 or more displays connected.

Would you mind starting a topic on the [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/) forum with as much detail you can find about this? That is the place where all the kernel experts hang out and I believe the best way to get this rolling (This answer shows you why I am suggesting this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1228323/15811 Also see the comment about using a mainline kernel).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I'll be sure to make a post when I have time since it seems like this problem only impacts very few users and probably won't have a fix for a while.

Answer (score 1):

@Joe S.
I am really sorry for the inconvenience. I did not know ubuntu-20.04 had a move compared to previous versions ,and since I did all my checks on iso using grub's loopback on iso sitting on hdd....

Anyway ,your usb stick is very probably still good ;all you have to do is

At boot prompt with "Try ubuntu without installing blabla"

1  Type "e"  to edit the line "Try ubuntu..."

2 Replace "maybe-ubiquity"  with "boot=casper"

3 Type F10  to boot

Everything should work now

Hope you get  thru

```
 cheers

 hoan3504
```

I only tried with gtx1650 on my acer nitro5. Would you try this liveimage I made which uses a modified prime using Mathieu Gras' idea; it allows live switch between intel and nvidia dgpu back and forth without rebooting.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox/files/bionic-nvidia/ubuntu-20.04-5.4.0-26-generic-nvidia-450.57-primeselect.iso

I tried running cuda-11.0 'samples: they are fully working
(nbody,oceanfft,fluidgl,smokedparticles with nvidia rendering)

Comment: Please make it clear in your post that you have made the image yourself. See https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried using the live image on my USB stick but it just boots to initramfs and says that there isn't any root device specified. I'll try troubleshooting it a bit more when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pop!_OS it has full support for Nvidia/AMD. I have the same laptop as you do and I run Pop and everything runs perfectly fine. https://pop.system76.com/

You can download an ISO to write as a bootable USB with the proprietary Nvidia driver preinstalled.

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful if you can evidence your claim. Show some pics...

Comment: @joe-taylor I'm also a user of Pop! with Ryzen CPU and Nvidia GPU. I think what @sun-bear is asking for is for you to take a screeenshot of `Settings > About` which will show the Motherboard, Processor, and Graphics details along with the OS version etc.

Comment: This might work, but I don't think "use a different OS" is a great answer (I haven't checked Meta, though). It would be better if you could show how using the OS that the OP is already using (Ubuntu 20.04)